# Android data SMS sent between two emulators gets truncated in transit

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I have not been able to find a posted answer to this question. Why does the length of a data SMS sent programatically from one emulator instance to another gets truncated on the receiving end?
Here I send 20 bytes from *emulator-554* to *emulator-556*, but *emulator-556* receives *only* 12 bytes:

---

emulator-554:  the SMS sender

```
/** Send data SMS between two emulators from 15555215554 to 15555215556. */
private void sendSMS()
{
    final int udLength = 20;  // SMS user data length in bytes
    Log.d("SMS TEST", "SMSActivity.sendSMS ud.length=" + udLength);
    byte[] payload = new byte[udLength];
    for (byte i = 0; i < udLength; i++)
    {
        Log.d("SMS TEST", "payload[" + i + "]=" + i);
        payload[i] = i;
    }

    Intent smsSentIntent = new Intent("SMS_SENT");
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, smsSentIntent, 0);
    String destTelephone = "15555215556";
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();       
    smsMgr.sendDataMessage(destTelephone, null, (short) 32766, payload, sentPI, null);
    Log.d("SMS TEST", "SMSActivity.sendSMS COMPLETED!");
}
```

Log on the sender emulator:

02-25 19:31:00.793: D/SMS TEST(257): onCreate
02-25 19:31:00.793: D/SMS TEST(257): onResume
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): SMSActivity.sendSMS ud.length=20
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[0]=0
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[1]=1
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[2]=2
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[3]=3
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[4]=4
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[5]=5
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[6]=6
02-25 19:31:00.823: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[7]=7
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[8]=8
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[9]=9
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[10]=10
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[11]=11
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[12]=12
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[13]=13
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[14]=14
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[15]=15
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[16]=16
02-25 19:31:00.833: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[17]=17
02-25 19:31:00.853: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[18]=18
02-25 19:31:00.853: D/SMS TEST(257): payload[19]=19
02-25 19:31:00.904: D/SMS TEST(257): SMSActivity.sendSMS COMPLETED!
02-25 19:31:27.044: D/SMS TEST(257): onPause
02-25 19:31:27.583: D/SMS TEST(257): onStop

---

emulator-556:  the SMS receiver

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    /** BroadcastReceiver listener. */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
        {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            Log.d("SMS TEST", "SmsReceiver.onReceive: pdus.length=" + pdus.length);
            SmsMessage inboundSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);  // pdus.length==1
            byte[] ud = inboundSMS.getUserData();
            int udLength = ud.length;
            Log.d("SMS TEST", "SmsReceiver.onReceive: ud.length=" + udLength);
            for (int i = 0; i < udLength; i++)
            {
                Log.d("SMS TEST", "ud[" + i + "]=" + ud[i]);
            }
            Log.d("SMS TEST", "SmsReceiver.onReceive COMPLETED!");
        }
    }
}
```

Log on the receiving emulator:

02-25 19:31:01.593: D/SMS TEST(258): SmsReceiver.onReceive: pdus.length=1
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): SmsReceiver.onReceive: ud.length=12
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[0]=0
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[1]=1
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[2]=2
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[3]=3
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[4]=4
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[5]=5
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[6]=6
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[7]=7
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[8]=8
02-25 19:31:01.613: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[9]=9
02-25 19:31:01.623: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[10]=10
02-25 19:31:01.623: D/SMS TEST(258): ud[11]=3
02-25 19:31:01.623: D/SMS TEST(258): SmsReceiver.onReceive COMPLETED!

---

As you see only the first 11 bytes of the data message are received ok.
The DDMS emulator control panel settings is `Data=home, Speed=Full, Latency=None`.
Using: `Android Development Toolkit 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534`
AVD target: `Android 2.2 (API level 8)`
`Eclipse SDK 3.6.2`

Is this an emulator issue? Can anybody else replicate this behavior? I have been stuck on this problem for too long. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It could be related with port number. Try to use port number less than 256.

Comment: I tried sending data using port 28 but still got the same result.